# Objective C Dismissing The Keyboard On Scroll of Another View [UIScrollViewKeyboardDismissModeInteractive]

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c, keyboard

I'm working on implementing a similar view to Apple's Messages app (iOS 7). I've already got all the code in place to have the toolbar attached to the top of the keyboard functionally.

The top portion of the screen is a red UICollectionView that scrolls through chat. There's a white box at the bottom of the screen with a UITextView and two buttons. **If you select that UITextView, then the keyboard pops up, and that white box will be attached to the top of the keyboard, and you'll type into that UITextView.**

[image]

Right now, I just want to be able place my finger on the red scroll space (collectionView) above the keyboard and toolbar, and scroll my finger down to the bottom of the screen to dismiss the keyboard. My keyboard is responding to the UITextView in between the BTN and the Send buttons. I can easily use `UIScrollViewKeyboardDismissModeInteractive` to get you to place your finger into the textInput view and drag and dismiss, however, when I attempt to use

```
self.collectionView.keyboardDismissMode = UIScrollViewKeyboardDismissModeInteractive;
```

The keyboard does not follow my finger as expected.

Does anybody know how I can get this to work? I've seen hacky solutions, but I'm close to getting this working and I think there's just something I'm missing. `self.collectionView` doesn't really have any relation to the keyboard, and I'm assuming I have to make some kind of relation in order to get this to work.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that `UIScrollViewKeyboardDismissModeInteractive` is about a keyboard summoned in response to a subview of *this* scroll view (e.g. a text field *inside* the scroll view). You are talking about a keyboard summoned in connection with a text field *outside* this scroll view. Thus `UIScrollViewKeyboardDismissModeInteractive` is irrelevant.

If the keyboard is to move in response to the movement of the scroll view, *you* will have to do it: implement the delegate methods of the scroll view for detecting that the user is scrolling, and change the keyboard's frame appropriately (or just dismiss it).

Comment: I suppose the one part of this I still don't get is how to position the keyboard. I want to be able to move the keyboard as if I was moving it with the DismissModeInteractive, like I could start to dismiss the keyboard, it follows my finger, and then I can bring it back up if I want by just moving my finger back up.

Comment: There is no "official" way, but if you search you'll probably find ways of working down the window-view hierarchy to find the view that is the window... That is why I suggested just dismissing the keyboard in response to the user scrolling your view. The "interactive" effect is going to be tricky to do.